# Attempting to login using Auth0 and Netlify w/ React although I get "undefined" in the URL when trying to login

Tags: reactjs, auth0, netlify

I wanted to deploy a react application which is a simple auth0 login page and on localhost:3000, eveything works fine, I can click the login button and everything works, it sends me to the auth0 login page.

Here is the part im stuck at:

When I push to Github and deploy to netlify and try to open it using the link netlify gave me, I click the login button and I get this in the URL bar: `https://undefined/authorize?redirect_uri=`

I have checked both the .env file in the app and on Netlify in the environments section and everything has the proper env variables. here is where I am testing it: https://reactjssample-324hz.netlify.app/

Here are the URIs I have setup:

Allowed Callback URLs:

```
http://localhost:3000,https://reactjssample-324hz.netlify.app
```

Allowed Logout URLs:

```
http://localhost:3000,https://reactjssample-324hz.netlify.app
```

Allowed Web Origins:

```
http://localhost:3000,https://reactjssample-324hz.netlify.app
```

Please tell me if I need to include anything such as code snippets.

EDIT: 06/01/2022
I have added the domain and clientID to the index.js file but now I am getting this when I click the login button:
[Netlify 404 page not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txvk7.png) although I have this in the URL bar now: `https://tubular-klepon-a1d5fc.netlify.app/authorize?client_id=` which I assume is better than what I had before.


EDIT: 06/02/2022
Here are the endpoint settings I have for my application
[endpoint settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmEQv.png)

Thanks

324hz
win1H2
he/him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like you have not configured the `YOUR_DOMAIN` in the application. Let try to configure it with value `reactjssample-324hz.netlify.app`

And do not forget to configure the customer domain `reactjssample-324hz.netlify.app` in Auth0 platform.

[configure YOUR_DOMAIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsxXR.png)

Hope it can help.

Comment: Hello Mj.phong,
looks like it does work all I need to do is figure out why Netlify is giving me a 404 page not found but I can see when i click the login button, it has the website followed by 

authorize?client_id=

Comment: Hi @324Hz. As far as I known, the end-point of authorization should be hosted in Auth0 domain, normally it looks like [https://xxxx.auth0.com/authorize]. You able to check it under navigation: Application > Setting > Advance (expand this section) > Endpoints

Comment: @324Hz, for more detail, could you share the screenshot of Application Setting (Auth0), and the config from your end?

Comment: Hello Mj.phong, I have updated the question with a screenshot of the endpoint settings.

Comment: Halo @324Hz. Have you configured the custom domain in your Auth0 setting? If you could not apply the custom domain on Netlify, you should use the domain which Auth0 is offering you (it is dev-xxx.us.auth0.com)

Comment: Hello Mj.phong, where would I configure the custom domain? would it be in the index.js file <Auth0Provider domain=""?

Comment: Ok so looks like it works when I put the dev-###.us.auth0.com in that field although when I press the login button I get a page that says: dev-0q65pe7d
Oops!, something went wrong

Comment: Yay, enjoy it @324